# Issue with "Serve" ruby gem and Apache server

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, apache, rubygems

I host the same application to 2 difference serves (Serve: localhost:4000 and Apache:localhost:80):

Here is the index.html source:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            var url = "http://shadow01.yumenetworks.com/dynamic_preroll_playlist.xml?domain=1552YmmwFStw";
            var successFn = function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            };
            $.get(url, successFn);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>>
```

And then I those servers one by one, and check the console log. The Apache:localhost:80 return data, but the Serve: localhost:4000 return empty Data.

Please help me know why?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change localhost:4000 to your_ip:4000 will work, look like your service detected your host is localhost so it does not return anything, this may be a security setting on server :)